# Как можно легче отобразить кнопку при всех заполненных инпутов?

Tags: vue.js

У меня такой пример https://jsfiddle.net/rusline/eywraw8t/389024/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
            return {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                button: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            showButton: function () {
                if (this.username !== '' && this.password !== '')
                    return this.button = true;
                else
                    return this.button = false;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit: function () {
                console.log(this)
            },
            onButton: function () {
                if (this.username !== '' && this.password !== '')
                    return this.button = true
                else
                    return this.button = false
            }
        }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <div>
                <label for="username">Логин</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" @change="onButton" v-model.trim="username">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Пароль</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" @change="onButton" v-model.trim="password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" v-show="button">Войти</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

То есть я примерно сделал там, что навесил событие на инпуты, но есть ли какой-то другой способ, чтобы присвоить значению button true?

Comment: Для большой формы можно сделать объект значений формы, после чего в цикле проверять заполненность. Ещё есть вариант использования watch, он вызывается при изменении значения поля, правда, тут тоже придется заводить объект для отслеживания и необходимо будет указать отслеживание в глубину. Но для Вашей небольшой формы у Вас все сделано оптимально))

Comment: И ещё момент - лучше не скрывать кнопку, а блокировать ее для нажатия. Отсутствие кнопки может ввести в ступор неподготовленного посетителя Вашего сайта))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже самое но без лишнего метода и проперти. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nh4yu8zt/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
            return {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit: function () {
                console.log(this)
            }
        }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <div>
                <label for="username">Логин</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" v-model.trim="username">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Пароль</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" v-model.trim="password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" v-show="password && username">Войти</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ну и как вам сказали в комментариях, что лучше кнопку делать неактивной чем просто прятать. Сделав кнопку такой:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" :class="password && username ? '': 'disabled'" type="submit">Войти</button>
```

Comment: disabled лучше ставить через атрибут `:disabled="disabled"` (чтобы использовать псевдокласс css) и передавать  в него свойство из computed которое возвращает true или false, [код](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/391084/).

Answer (score 1):

При вводе в инпут вешаем функцию на события клавиатуры `<input @keypress="showButton" ...>`, которая будет возвращать булевое значение,

эту же функцию подключаем к кнопке `<button v-show="showButton" ...>`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      // button: false // это больше не нежно
    };
  },
  computed: {
      showButton() {
         // Просто возвращаем булевое значение
         // дополнительные проверки ненужны
         return this.username !== '' && this.password !== '';
      }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <div>
        <label for="username">Логин</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          name="username"
          class="form-control"
          v-model.trim="username"
          @keypress="showButton" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Пароль</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          name="password"
          class="form-control"
          v-model.trim="password"
          @keypress="showButton" />
      </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          type="submit"
          v-show="showButton">
          Войти
        </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: computed как обработчик события не надо использовать